# In .NET Windows Forms why use Activated and Deactivate

Tags: .net, windows, forms

In .NET Windows Forms, if we need to add code that executes either when the form is being displayed or when the form is being hidden, we will add the code to the Activated and Deactivate event handlers instead of to the GotFocus and LostFocus event handlers. WHY?

In .NET Windows Forms, if the form is not already loaded into memory when the Hide method is called, what does the Hide method do?

Comment: I believe the answer to your first question is that only a single control ever has focus, so your form can be 'activated', while a textbox within the form actually has focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input focus is a different concept to a form being activated. A single control within your application can have focus at any one time, as this determines where keyboard input will be sent. This means that even if your form did get the focus, it would lose it when a child control (such as a textbox) within the form was clicked on. Therefore we have separate Activated/Deactivated events on the form to track when it is the active window.

Calling Hide() on a form simply sets the Visible property to false, so calling Hide() on a form that is already invisible will have no effect.

Comment: Well if the form is not loaded, when u call show() it will load the form and show it. Why the same situation, it won't load it first and then set it invisible?

Comment: I suppose a form needs to be loaded before it can be shown, whereas there's no need to load it if it's not being shown, so they don't (I've just tested this myself to confirm).